# Firewall-rules for google compute engine being deleted

Tags: node.js, websocket, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Long story short, I'm trying to setup a secure socket connection on compute engine but everytime I add a firewall rule through

`gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-websockets \
    --allow tcp:65080 \
    --target-tags websocket \
    --description "Allow websocket traffic on port 65080"`

it just disappears from the rules list after a while. Target-tags are in place for my server and the https connection is ok (I'm using a self-signed certificate for tests, but I don't think this has anything to do with the problem).

I even tried creating the rule through the cloud platform console, same configuration, using the 0.0.0.0/0 ip, but got the same result. It works for about 10 minutes then the rule just vanishes.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try going to https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer and apply a filter on the firewall rule that you have. Also check the instances that have that tag to see if its being removed. The logs should be able to tell you who is removing the rules. Also make sure that the firewall rules are properly being applied. Each request returns an operation which if something goes wrong will have information to tell you what happened.

Comment: @caio-vertematti I am facing the same issue of firewall rules automatically getting deleted.  Did you happen to figure out why?  Thanks.

Comment: Studying the logs (from Jeremy Edwards' comment) led me to the answer, which in my case was that my organization had set up a policy that was automatically deleting the rules.